# How change the title of a page before it loads JSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, jsx

I want change the title of a class, and I achieve it with document.title = "flayers" but I put this code in the constructor,then firt I have a default title and change it then when I refer to the url, show the old title.

first I have this title

[image]

next I change for this 
[image]

and when I refer to url : [image]

I don't know if I explain :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with React-Router? You can change the name of the title page by placing a componentDidMount in the desired component, which will fire when the component is loaded. Then, you'll simply use document.title to target and change the page's title.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/49), which I took from issue ticket #49 in the React-Router Github repository:

```
var Handler = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function() {
document.title = "Amazing Page";
}
});
```

Comment: yep, But I need change the title before that View is load

Comment: ah. try changing the title by using an event handler! that way, when the title is clicked, the title will change as the view loads

Comment: This is the same problem as mine, better explained
 https://github.com/google/physical-web/issues/595 but I use react js and JSX